# How to use django ORM to query database

Tags: python, django

I have a model called 'dboinv_product' and this model has a field called 'product_name'

I need to use Django ORM in my views.py file to pull ALL the product names. The goal is to put it into a list this way I can serialize it using JSON.

Does anyone know which Django command(s) can be used to produce this list?

Essentially, I need the equivalent of "SELECT ALL product_name FROM dbo.inv_product"

Comment: To clarify, my project is in working order. I have database connectivity, my migrations are up to date. I simply need help determining how to use Django ORM. I have used SQL statements previously. I have gone over the documentation on Django's website, but I am having little luck piecing it together.

Comment: did you check query documentation and what did you try https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-all-objects

Comment: First I tried

products = dboinv_product.objects.all()
    list_of_products = products.product_name

but this returns an error stating there is no attribute 'product_name' which doesn't make sense so I figured I did something wrong

Comment: products is queryset which you should iterate

Comment: It will be better if you put your first comment and what you tried in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`values_list` is what you are looking for.

```
value= dboinv_product.objects.values_list('product_name', flat=True)
list = list(value) # to convert to a list

# flat=True to get list rather than tuple inside of the ValuesListQuerySet.
```

The document about `values_list`is here. [1](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list)

Comment: This is great, thank you! Only trouble is now I need to determine how to make this JSON serializable, as a query set is not